# Is there a way to show "[current] of [tota]" of the search in file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, when using Ctrl F in a file, the editor shows the "current of total" of the searched string. Is there a way to enable this in Visual Studio 2019?

VS Code:

[image]

Visual Studio 2019 Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `Ctrl+F` use `Ctrl+Shift+F`, this will open the `Find in Files` option, select `Current Document` and search.

The results will now appear in a new window and you will get the count at the bottom of the window.

I don't think there's an option to show this count in `Quick Find`, at least not in Visual Studio for Windows. In Visual Studio for Mac this is the default behaviour:

[image]